# Audacity - moving the waveform graph up/down

Tags: audacity

I'm working in Audacity. What I need to do is to move the entire waveform graph up by a certain value. So for example all points with a value of 0 are supposed to become 10, every 10 is supposed to become 20, every -10 should become 0 and so on, for every point and every value.
What I'm trying to do is the opposite of removing DC offset. I want to introduce an offset, and not just any offset. A specific value.

I'm aware that the graph will not be centered after the operation, that's exactly what I'm going for. (I need to misalign it by a very specific value, so it cancels out very specific portions of the other track. Reasons are unimportant.)

Answer (score 1):

Well, turns out there is an Audacity plugin meant to achieve just that.
It's called DC Offset Tool and it's currently available here:
https://forum.audacityteam.org/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=68463

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this in Audacity. If I were going to attempt this, I would use a programming language to read the PCM data, add a fixed value to each data point and save the result.

My experience is with Java. Other languages can probably do this as well. But I'd try and use something where you aren't doing the .wav parsing yourself--better to have a language that can get you to the PCM data, as Java can with an AudioInputStream.  But I certainly wouldn't attempt trying to learn Java Audio API just for the sake of doing this.